# Help me pick the perfect string!

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, maintenance, semi-acoustic-guitar

I busted my strings while trying to tune by ear.

[This](https://kadence.in/?product=kadence-acoustica-guitar-36-inch) is my guitar.

As for the type of music I am looking to learn, I'd say it would be rock and blues. I also love Tommy Emmanuels which is to say that I am also looking to learn fingerstyle (without the thumbpick).I will probably be playing mostly in E standard.

With my current strings, I am able to fingerpick just fine, but when it comes to doing barre chords (in the first few frets near the nut), it proves to be near impossible. I have literally taken the guitar on my lap, squashed the strings with my THUMB and still failed to produce a clean strum, let alone using my index finger.

I decided on these [strings](https://www.bajaao.com/products/ernieball-hybrid-slinky-2151-acoustic-guitar-strings-phosphor-bronze-10-52?variant=14018755715) for the following reasons:

-Phosphor , so prolonged lifespan( idc about volume all too much)

-Reduced tension would help me barre more easily at the places where I am currently struggling and also allow me to experiment with some bending. Probably help in a solo I suppose.

But I have some concerns:

-Would I be able to play strumming songs like say, Wonderwall or Boulevard of Broken dreams without worrying about them breaking?

-Would these strings be able to handle the 25'' scale length of my guitar?

Any suggestions/correction and most importantly advice is needed!

Answer (score 1):

25" scale is fairly common, and often acoustic guitars with that are sold with .011s, so .010s will be fine. I'd go (and often do) to .009s, or even .008s, but that's me.

With standard tuning, there should be no breakages strumming. Maybe you need to examine your technique, and not strum so hard, and feather the pick better.

Your problem with barring could well be the *action* which could be too high, meaning it's difficult to press down with as little effort as it should be. For now, you could try tuning down a semitone, like so many have and still do. This relieves the tension a little, making barring easier.

People tell me that thin strings break more easily: in 50 years using them, I've never found it to be true.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do thin strings feel flimsy or awkward when doing power chords?

Comment: My strumming isn't all too hard, and I usually strum moderately hard using the nail of my index finger (it feels far more comfortable)

Comment: @chirag - no, I don't think so - one can get used to the feel. Having said that, I don't play 'power chords' - they just don't do anything for me! Using a fingernail, how do you upstrum?

Comment: I use my index for the downstrum and my thumb for the upstrum. But I use a pick when I feel some discomfort or I just want it to be less mellow.

Comment: is ernie ball a reliable brand?

Comment: Only used them for 30+ yrs. Not sure yet...

Comment: Haha.K Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find a "perfect string" is a huge red herring.  How do you know you have a half way descent guitar, or pick, or proper finger nails, or technique?

If you cannot do barre chords it could be the action on the guitar, in which case no string will feel good.  But you should also know that it takes years to develop proper technique and feel in the hands.  Once you get it right you won't remember how or why you couldn't do it but you need patience. Even if the guitar is set up beautifully and have a good quality set of light gauge strings you might still have trouble getting a clean sound on some chords until you've put in the 10k hours of practice.

As a comparison, I use medium gauge Martin bronze strings on my 12 string and strum with all my might at times (for example playing Pinball Wizard by The Who) and never break a string.  It might help to know where they break (if and when they do).  If it's at a certain fret then they frets need filing (to be dressed).  If it's by the bridge then the grooves for the string might be too sharp.

Comment: It broke at the tuning knob for me, so I don't know for sure if I have overly exertive strumming. But assuming I do, by perfect I meant if that set of strings would allow me some room to strum that way or not, along with having the ease of playing.

Comment: It is still a red herring.   You need to have someone knowledgeable do a complete set up so everything is adjusted correctly.   No matter what, you can always break a string.   Are you taking lessons and are you s beginner?

Comment: Did it break at the tuning peg or nut?

Comment: The peg. I am learning by myself online after picking up the instrument after nearly 3  years (starting from scratch all over again).